# From which table can the customer name be retrieved?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to retrieve the customer name. But in table `CustTable` there is no field for the customer name. From which table can the customer name be retrieved?

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the name using the method `name()` in table `CustTable`.

Select the table `CustTable` and then pass on the result of the method `name()`.

**Example:**

```
CustTable custTable;
select custTable where custTable.AccountNum == "YourCustomer";
info(custTable.name());
```

Comment: hi Jonathan how can i pass the field in the SSRS Report

Comment: customerInvoiceTmp.Customername=??What should i pass there??

Comment: Yes, Use that field, then use the same field in the SSRS Report to show it.

Comment: customerInvoiceTmp.Customername=DirPartyTable.Name; This is correct??

Comment: The relation is in this table (**DirPartyTable**) If the table **DirPartyTable** properly filtered, yes is correct.

Comment: @VinothYesuraj: Please create new questions for follow up questions. Try to avoid asking them in comments, as this makes it harder for other people to find these questions and their answer.